# What is the difference between "cache misses" and "in memory cache misses" in Ehcache?

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm looking in the EhCache statistics, I see these figures:

> CacheMisses: 75977
> CacheHits: 38151
>
> InMemoryCacheMisses: 4843
> InMemoryCacheHits: 38151

"memory" is the only store - no off-heap and no disk storage (`overflowToDisk="false", diskPersistent="false"`). So what does these two mean? I would expect them to be the same (the hits are the same), but the misses differ greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some `null`-valued `Element`s in your cache? (Ehcache allows you to store `Element`s with `null` values, but I'm not sure if there's any constraints surrounding that).

Looking at the code for [Cache.searchInStoreWithStats(Object key)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.3/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.java#Cache.searchInStoreWithStats%28java.lang.Object%29) in version 2.5.3, it seems that there is a bug there:

- The test determining whether to increment `inMemoryMisses` uses a `containsKey()` derivative,
- whereas the test for incrementing `cacheMisses` null-checks against the result of a `get()` derivative.

So, each time you search for a key which exists in the `InMemoryStore` but has a `null` value, it will increment `cacheMisses` but not `inMemoryMisses`.

So, I might be completely off, but it smells right to me. What do you think?

**Edit:** I've realised my interpretation was wrong - the Element can't be null, (but its 'value' can be null). I'll leave this answer here anyway incase it triggers any other ideas

Comment: I think I noticed the same issue a couple of years ago, and didn't report it. More fool me!

Comment: note: that method is still unchanged in the trunk: http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/ehcache/trunk/ehcache/ehcache-core/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.java

Comment: good point. I don't think I have nulls, but I'll check. I already reported the discrepancy as an issue, waiting for response

Comment: you know what, my suspicion was wrong! The element would not be null, even if the value were null. Anyway maybe this idea will trigger a better idea for you. Good luck

Comment: @laher or Bozho any of you guys find a reason behind this I'm experiencing similar behaviour with my cache. Same value for hits and misses in the cache but only one inMemoryMiss

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using ehcache 2.5+ . If you have cacheconfiguration with diskpersistance to true ( though overflowtodisk is false) , it writes to disk.  So there could be diskhits as well? You can view them in the Statistics. do you have diskpersistance as true? Please post your cache configuration

Comment: both are false. zero disk hits and misses